# How do i pass an array to mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

ok so i have a problem i need to pass an array of product ids to my sql statement below

```
$index = 0;
  $products = $cart->get_products();
  for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($products); $i<$n; $i++) {
   $prod = $products[$index]['id'];

 if (strpos($prod,"{")){
 $product = preg_split("^[{}]^",$prod);
 }else{
 $product = $prod;
 }
 }
$product_query = tep_db_query("select cb.products_id, SUM(cb.customers_basket_quantity),SUM(p.products_rate)  from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p INNER JOIN " . TABLE_CUSTOMERS_BASKET . " cb ON p.products_id = cb.products_id   
WHERE cb.customers_id ='" . $customer_id ."'
AND p.products_id IN '".$product ."'
");
```

the results are always

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Array'' at line 3
```

select cb.products_id, SUM(cb.customers_basket_quantity),SUM(p.products_rate) from products p INNER JOIN customers_basket cb ON p.products_id = cb.products_id WHERE cb.customers_id ='3' AND p.products_id IN 'Array'

Comment: could you give us var_dump($product)?

Comment: The syntax is just wrong. What you need to achieve is `... WHERE p.products_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)`. By just passing the array into the string only `Array` will be inserted there.

Comment: the array returns 1{4}1{3}5 for certain products that have options associated with them so i guess is how can i separate the first character? 1 by the way which is my product id

Comment: Switch to MySQLi or PDO, and use prepared statements rather than creating problems for yourself in the future with the deprecated MySQL extension

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> string(9) "1{4}1{3}5" ["name"]=> string(15) "Matrox G200 MMS" ["model"]=> string(8) "MG200MMS" ["image"]=> string(19) "matrox/mg200mms.gif" ["price"]=> string(8) "299.9900" ["quantity"]=> string(1) "1" ["weight"]=> string(5) "23.00" ["final_price"]=> float(299.99) ["tax_class_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["attributes"]=> array(2) { [4]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(1) "5" } } }

Comment: unfortunatly the shop i'm running off of runs mysql how do i upgrade?

Comment: ok the var_dump($product) returns array

Comment: It's also very confusing to have 3 vars with pretty much the same name: prod, product, products.

Answer (score 2):

**(Be VERY careful about what you're inserting into your SQL if you're making it yourself (instead of PDO params etc)!)**

Make sure $product is an array:

```
$product = (array)$product;
```

And then escape its values:

```
$product = array_map('your_db_escape_function', $product);
```

And then stringify it:

```
$product = "'" . implode("', '", $product) . "'";
```

And then add it to the query:

```
"... p.products_id IN (" . $product . ")"
```

After your code edit, I assume this is what you want:

```
$products = $cart->get_products();
$productIds = array_map(function($product) {
    return (int)$product['id'];
}, $products);
$productIds = implode(', ', $productIds);

$query = tep_db_query("
    select cb.products_id, SUM(cb.customers_basket_quantity),SUM(p.products_rate)
    from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p
    INNER JOIN " . TABLE_CUSTOMERS_BASKET . " cb ON p.products_id = cb.products_id
    WHERE cb.customers_id ='" . $customer_id ."'
    AND p.products_id IN (" . $productIds . ")
");
```

Comment: ok have modified code

Answer (score 0):

make it like this `IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` using `implode(',', $product);`

Answer (score 0):

ok figured it out! it was a variable that i needed so it now reads

```
$id = $this->rate($id);
   $qty = $cart->count_contents($id);
```

which returns the proper qty in my formula!

Comment: but not for multiple products for ex 1 product has 1 flat rate shipping another product has free shipping so i would like the shipping to reflect this